# Condition snippets in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, code-snippets

I've been trying to add a snippet/autocomplete in VSCode that works only inside quotes, for easily adding interpolation. Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
"Ruby string interpolation": {
    "if": "insideString",
    "prefix": "#",
    "body": ["#{$1:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}"],
    "description": "Add interpolation",
}
```

should generate

```
"abc #" => "abc #{}"
```

This easily works in Atom, but I've kept searching and can't figure out how to do it for VSCode.

Comment: I know some things that work in Emacs but not in VSC

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+Shift+Space` after typing the prefix

Answer (score 0):

Update:
There is an extension called `#{ruby}` that adds the desired functionality. I just couldn't find it previously.

Old anwser:

Seeing no other way I've resorted to keybindings to call my snippet.

In snippets:

```
"Ruby string interpolation": {
    "prefix": "#",
    "body": ["#{${1:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}"],
    "description": "Add interpolation",
}
```

In keybindings:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+3",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {"name": "Ruby string interpolation"}
}
```

Instead of using Shift+3, just using Cmd+3. In a way this feels quite better.